# Passing event to DOM element underneath

Tags: jquery, events, mouse, seadragon

I have developped this web application which uses Microsoft Seadragon Technology.

On top of the Seadragon viewport, the user can draw measurements and annotations.  Those annotations are drawn into a Canvas on top of the Seadragon.

In order to be able to edit the annotation, my application has to be into "Edit Annotation" mode.  What this mode does, it simply removes the CSS style pointer-events: none; from the annotation canvas.  When this mode is off, I put back the pointer-events: none; to the annotation canvas so that the Seadragon viewport can receive the mouse events.

The problem I have is that the pointer-events property is not supported by IExplorer and Opera.  Since the annotation canvas is drawn on top of the Seadragon viewport, in IExplorer9 and Opera, I can NEVER have the mouse event to reach the Seadragon Viewport.

I gave it a try by passing the mouseevent to the DOM element used to created the Seadragon viewport, but it does not seem to work.

$('#annotationCanvas').mousedown(function(){ $('#seadragonVP').trigger('mousedown'); });

But this does not work...

Can someone help me on how to :

1. Either pass the mouse event to elements underneath another element
2. or to call directly the mouse events from Seadragon

You can have a look at the application at : http://fibics.interplex.ca

Thanks!

Comment: are any of the contents you want to manipulate inserted after the page is loaded?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem, but "Since the annotation canvas is drawn on top of the Seadragon viewport" changing the z-index might help...

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the browser.  For example, Seadragon draws on the canvas when using Firefox, but it inserts new images (and uses CSS to position them) when using Chrome or IE.

Comment: Changing the z-index will not work here since I always want the annotation canvas to be drawn on top of the seadragon element.  Having a lower z-index for measurements will work for the mouse event, but will "hide" the measurement underneath the Seadragon element.

Comment: Sorry Yoda, here is a better answer. Yes, I want to manipulate the content after the page is loaded : user should be able to add annotation once the page is fully loaded.

Comment: I have solved my problem! Thanks to Aseem!  Essentially, I had to use the mousetracker object of my seadragon viewer and assign all the mouse event to a new mousetracker of my measurementCanvas sitting on top of the seadragon viewer.